# Attachments getting attached twice using smptplib in python

Tags: python, smtplib

I am trying to implement a functionality in python where I want to send a 
file as an attachment to an email alert
Everything works fine. i am getting the email alert with required subject    but the only problem is that I get the same attachment twice in my email alert.

```
    fileMsg = email.mime.base.MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    fileMsg.set_payload(file('/home/bsingh/python_files/file_dict.txt').read())
    #email.encoders.encode_base64(fileMsg)
    fileMsg.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename=LogFile.txt')
    emailMsg.attach(fileMsg)

  # send email
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username, password)
    server.sendmail(from_add, to_addr,emailMsg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. How does `emailMsg` come to be?

Comment: emailMsg = email.MIMEMultipart.MIMEMultipart('alternative')

Comment: everything works... its just a part of code that I have shown here...just the problem is I am getting attachment twice and I want only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the version..Has been resolved

Answer (score 6):

I have been having problems with this myself. I had `'alternative'` as my message's MIMEMultipart type. When I changed to the default, `'mixed'`, the duplicate disappeared.

So if you created `emailMsg` using `MIMEMultipart('alternative')`, you may have the same problem.

I believe `'alternative'` is for offering both a text and html version of the message body, so I think you need to offer both in addition to your attachment if you use it.

I hope that helps.

I have not found a good explanation of this anywhere yet; email can get pretty complicated.

Comment: mixed worked for me when attaching a PDF...with alternative I was getting the file attached twice. Glad I stumbled on this one because I was chasing my tail.

Comment: Setting the MIMEMultipart type to 'mixed' breaks emails that have text and HTML versions of the body, i.e. the body gets repeated twice.

Answer (score 3):

The whole purpose of [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) (I'm the developer) is to make it really easy to send emails, especially with HTML or attachment needs.

Please try the following code:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP(from_add, password)
contents = ['See my attachment below', '/home/bsingh/python_files/file_dict.txt']
yag.send(contents = contents)
```

Notice the magic here: `contents` is a list, where an item equal to a file path will automatically be loaded, mimetype guessed, and attached.

There's a lot more magic involved, such as easy to embed images, passwordless scripts, usernameless scripts, easy aliases, smart defaults (notice I omitted the `to` and `subject` arguments?) and much more. I advise/encourage you to read its [github](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) page :-). Feel free to raise issues or add feature requests!

You can get yagmail by using pip to install it:

```
pip install yagmail # Python 2
pip3 install yagmail # Python 3
```

Comment: my mail is already going through this along with the attachment...only issue is attachment is going twice n i want to resolve it..

Comment: @ShrutiSrivastava Using this package will save you lines of codes (literally these 4 lines are all you need), will make your life very comfortable and most importantly,  attach only once.

Comment: what about the subject of the email...can i edit that too?

Comment: @ShrutiSrivastava Just change to `yag.send(subject="My subject", contents = contents)`.

Comment: Most commonly I do like `yag.send('to@gmail.com', 'My subject', ['some body text followed by attachment, '/local/file/test.txt']`. Consider reading the [github page](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) for all options :)

Comment: @ShrutiSrivastava Then it probably has to do with the rest of the code.

Comment: @ PascalvKooten well let me check..i vl come back to you after that

Comment: @ShrutiSrivastava Did you in fact run just those 4 lines (with specifying the variables yourself?)

Comment: @ShrutiSrivastava It simply has to be that you are in some kind of loop.

Comment: no i have a lot of code before and after that so i vl need some time to check..but definitely its not a loop becoz if i try to comment emailMsg.attach(fileMsg) then mail goes without any attachment

Comment: @ShrutiSrivastava The problem is still somewhere outside of this code. Try just running these 4 lines and you'll see that there will be only 1 attachment. Most likely `emailMsg.attach(fileMsg)` happens twice, without making a new unique `emailMsg`.